# Any word embedding methods that keep lexicological order?

Tags: tokenize, word-embedding

I want to turn a string into a feature vector but also keeps its lexicological order (actually it is the only thing I care about for the vector).

I know that ASCII value is the easiest way(?) to do so ("abc123"->[97,98,99,49,50,51]). But it seems not that intuitive with respect to the string order. Say we can set a max string length of 3, then the distance between 'am9' and 'ama' should be 1 but it isn't if using ASCII values.

Comment: Why not assign your own ordering?

Comment: Cus I am not really sure what characters I will meet in the test set. e.g all strings in my data consist of letters only, but I may meet other types of characters in the future like period, comma, hyphen or even foreign language characters. Also, long strings in the future will have similar questions.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your vector?

Comment: Also, when you say that the distance between `am9` and `ama` is `1`, do you mean their distance is `1` because only one character is different?

Comment: yes. it's kind of like the edit distance as I set the max length to 3.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the strings to integer values if all you want to know is the number of characters that are different between two strings?